# Applying .isin for multiple series in a DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have three fields TEL1, TEL2, TEL3 which I want to look to see if values exist in another DF. I can do one column at a time, but was wondering if there was a quick way I could hide rows if any of the three fields contains a value in the lookup Dataframe.

I am currently using:

```
df1 = Sample['TEL1'].isin(DNC['NUMBER'])
```

Dataframe I am looking up against:

```
    NUMBER
0   555
```

Dataframe I am looking up:

```
    TEL1 TEL2 TEL3 NAME
0   222  555  555  BEN
1   222  555  222  BEN
2   555  222  555  BEN
3   222  222  222  BEN
4   555  555  555  BEN
```

Expected result (row that does not contain 555 in TEL1-TEL3 columns):

```
    TEL1 TEL2 TEL3 NAME
3   222  222  222  BEN
```

Thank you in advance, Ben.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can us `isin` on the entire dataframe (or with the columns you are interested in) and then check which rows are all `False` (ie, *not* have *any*).

```
ix = ~df.loc[:, 'TEL1':'TEL3'].isin(DNC['NUMBER'].values).any(axis=1)
df.loc[ix]
```

Notice I used the values of `DNC['NUMBER']` because it will try to match the index otherwise. So it'll look for `555` in the dataframe where index is `0` if you keep it as a series.

Comment: Thanks so much this is perfect. The numbers will change from just 555, so it's great that it can still be dynamic.